# How to get Callbacks from Chrome Tabs in android like web View provides shouldOverrideUrlLoading, onLoadResource, onPageFinished

Tags: android, google-chrome, webview, chrome-custom-tabs

I am trying to replace the web view with Chrome Custom tabs in my project. For replacing webview, I need a callback in the Chrome tab like the android web view provides. So are there any callbacks available or not and if available, then what are they? Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6):

you can only provide the following callbacks in chrome custom tabs:

```
/**
* Sent when the tab has started loading a page.
*/
public static final int NAVIGATION_STARTED = 1;

/**
* Sent when the tab has finished loading a page.
*/
public static final int NAVIGATION_FINISHED = 2;

/**
* Sent when the tab couldn't finish loading due to a failure.
*/
public static final int NAVIGATION_FAILED = 3;

/**
* Sent when loading was aborted by a user action before it finishes like clicking on a link
* or refreshing the page.
*/
public static final int NAVIGATION_ABORTED = 4;

/**
* Sent when the tab becomes visible.
*/
public static final int TAB_SHOWN = 5;

/**
* Sent when the tab becomes hidden.
*/
public static final int TAB_HIDDEN = 6;
```

To attach a callback, bind to the custom tabs service as normal, and just pass your callback while calling newSession().

more info: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/customtabs/CustomTabsClient.html#newSession(android.support.customtabs.CustomTabsCallback)

implementation guide: https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/android/customtabs#implementationguide

Answer (score 5):

It is not possible in custom chrome tab in android.